# error in add-iam-policy-binding to ESP end point service GCloud

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am trying to create an end point for an API to be deployed into existing GKE cluster by following the instructions in [Getting started with Cloud Endpoints for GKE with ESPv2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine-espv2)

I clone the sample code in the repo and modified the content of openapi.yaml:

```
# [START swagger]
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
  title: "Endpoints Example"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "my-api.endpoints.my-project.cloud.goog"
```

I then deployed it via the command:

```
endpoints/getting-started (master) $ gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi.yaml
```

Now I can see that it has been created:

```
$ gcloud endpoints services list
NAME                                                         TITLE
my-api.endpoints.my-project.cloud.goog
```

I also have postgreSQL service account:

```
$ gcloud iam service-accounts list
DISPLAY NAME                   EMAIL                          DISABLED
my-postgresql-service-account  my-postgresql-service-acco@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com  False
```

In the section **Endpoint Service Configuration** of documentation it says to add the role to the attached service account for the endpoint service as follows, but I get this error:

```
$ gcloud endpoints services add-iam-policy-binding my-api.endpoints.my-project.cloud.goog 
--member serviceAccount:my-postgresql-service-acco@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
--role roles/servicemanagement.serviceController
ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.add-iam-policy-binding) User [myusername@mycompany.com] does not have permission to access services instance [my-api.endpoints.my-project.cloud.goog:getIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): No access to resource: services/my-api.my-project.cloud.goog
```

The previous lines show the service exits, I guess? Now I am not sure how to resolve this? What permissions do I need? who can give me permission and what permissions he should have? how can I check? Is there any other solution?

Comment: I find Cloud Endpoints to be a particularly gnarly deployment. After you `gcloud endpoints services deploy ${SERVICE}`, did you `gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}`?

Comment: Yes, I did successfully run $gcloud services enable my-api.endpoints.my-project.cloud.goog

Comment: I think it's a red-herring but what role(s) does `myusername@mycompany.com` have on the project?

Comment: How could I check with role(s) do I have? Is there any command to list them?

Comment: I found this command $gcloud iam roles list --project=my-project

Comment: The answer is interesting: Listed 0 items.

Comment: Apologies, you can `gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} --flatten=bindings[].members --filter=bindings.members=user:${EMAIL} --format="value(bindings.role)"` where `PROJECT` is the GCP Project ID and `EMAIL` is your email address: `myusers@...`

Comment: Thanks, I run the command and got the roles of roles/editor
roles/pubsub.editor which seems to be correct. I also went to console and on IAM page for the project, I found other roles exist such as "Project Admin" and "Tech Support Editor", is any of them would be good, what is minimal role which is needed

Comment: Editor should be sufficient. I'm at a loss. I've not used Endpoints recently with GKE. I'm using it with Cloud Run and that command isn't needed.

Comment: Are you using Workload Identity? Or, is the service account you used in the failed command the node service account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved after I was assigned the role of "Project_Admin". It was not ideal as it was giving too much permission to me. The role "roles/endpoints.portalAdmin" was also tried but did not help.

Comment: Is that a custom role? What permissions did you use?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I am not sure if is custom role, it seems so though.

Comment: I suggest inspecting in IAM & Admin > Roles, there you should be able to see what permissions the role is made of, you can check also there that the role is a custom one.